# How to view Precision, Recall, F1 in custom SpaCy tag training?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I try to train a custom POS tagger with Spacy, but when I run training:

```
python -m spacy train config.cfg --output ./output
```

I get the following training metrics:

```
E    #       LOSS TOK2VEC  LOSS TAGGER  TAG_ACC  SCORE                                                                                       
---  ------  ------------  -----------  -------  ------                                                                                      
  0       0          0.00        56.47    34.57    0.35                                                                                      
  0     200        220.60      9159.67    75.71    0.76                                                                                      
  0     400        416.10      8008.25    80.36    0.80                                                                                      
  0     600        574.27      8974.13    82.15    0.82                                                                                      
  1     800        683.66      8606.33    82.96    0.83
```

However, in different tutorials and examples, I can see additional metrics that would be nice to see as well:

```
E # LOSS TOK2VEC LOSS NER ENTS_F ENTS_P ENTS_R SCORE
```

(True, these are mostly indicated in case of NER training, not POS training examples, but I cannot see any reason why not to indicate them in case of POS as well).
I suspect that it could be customized by the following line in `config.cfg`:

```
scorer = {"@scorers":"spacy.tagger_scorer.v1"}
```

but I'm not sure how to actually edit this to get the desired output.

By the way, what is `score` metric in this context, and why does `loss tok2vec` keep increasing during the training (while `accuracy` improves)?